# Why does I18n not work when in android 5.0.2?

Tags: android, internationalization

I want change language to English,but it doesn't work when it is android 5.0.2 phone. And it's normal when it is android 7.1.1. 
Here is my code：

```
 public static void applyLanguage(Context context, String newLanguage) {
        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(newLanguage)) {
            return;
        }
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        Locale locale = SupportLanguageUtil.getSupportLanguage(newLanguage);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
            createConfigurationResources(context, newLanguage);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                configuration.setLocale(locale);
            }else {
                configuration.locale = locale;
            }
            DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, dm);
        }
    }
```

However in an English default Language Environment, I change it to Chinese normally. This is very strange. Is anyone meet with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing Locale.ENGLISH to Locale.US in that I set a language resources of US.